# drive not showing in Windows setup

Tags: windows-7

I accidentally formatted my OEM drive of M DELL Inspiron.
After that I could not install Windows 7 on my laptop. Because the partitions of my hard disk are not showing to select an install drive. I downloaded the RAID driver from the Dell Support website for my laptop, but the driver is showing and I loaded the driver from a pen drive. But it's still not showing the drives.

Comment: Is the hard drive showing up in Windows 7 install, with no partitions? If so, create partitions in Windows 7 install. Or, is the hard drive not showing up at all? If so, the issue is not partitions. Something else is wrong, likely in the BIOS, or H/W has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in the BIOS try changing the SATA mode.  Its probably in Native and can be changed to Disabled, setup should see it like a normal drive (Not as a RAID drive)

Comment: Or, change SATA mode to IDE mode, depends on the BIOS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Hiren 9.x CD , go to the partition manager section > Smart Partition tool .
delete any none FAT-NTFS drive if you have , and then create a drive with NTFS/FAT format.
now you are ready to install windows 7

Comment: This isn't going to help. The OP stated that the drives are not detected at all.

Answer (score 0):

Look for an AHCI driver, not a RAID driver. That should do it hopefully.